# Why are the quotes necessary in this code?

Tags: java, string, quote

Hi sorry if this is a dumb question, probably is... this is from codingbat (exercise: everNth)

why is it that this works?

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
String characters = "";

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i + n) {
characters = characters + Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
}

return characters;
}
```

but this one doesn't?

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i + n) {
return Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
}

}
```

^^ gives me the error: "This method must return a result of type String"

However, doesn't the Character.string() method already create a string?

Why do I have to add in additional quotation marks? Thanks guys!!~~ peace and love

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the quotation marks.  The problem is that you don't have a `return` statement *after* the `for` loop.

The compiler is warning you that if the `for` loop is never entered, then you will never return anything.  You need to make sure your method returns a string value under *all* circumstances, not just when the loop is entered.

To better understand, walk through your method, and consider what would happen if `str` has a length of zero.  What would your method return then?

**EDIT**

However, as pointed out by WalterM, keep in mind that, even if you fix the compiler error, your 2nd method's logic is different from your first one.  The 2nd method only ever returns the 1st character of the string.

Comment: sstan you are a saint <3

Comment: Judging from his method name. I think he wants to return `everyNth` letter, not just the first one.

Comment: @WalterM: Good point. OP may want to look into that.

Comment: true, thanks WalterM <3

Comment: w8 srry guys, why isn't the for loop doing what it usually does and executing the code multiple times?

Comment: Because on the first iteration, `i` will always be equal to `0`.  It's only on the 2nd iteration that `i` is incremented by `n`, but by then, it's too late.  The first iteration has already returned the character at position `0`.  Remember that as soon as a `return` statement is executed, the method execution ends.  It won't continue looping.